# Ubuntu 20.04 (upgraded from 18.04) needs manual initramfs update, after every auto-update. How can I solve/automate this?

Tags: 20.04, updates, initramfs

I have an issue with Ubuntu 20.04, since I upgraded from 18.04. Every time the software updater updates Ubuntu base I need to manually update *initramfs* , otherwise my PC won't boot.

```
1. sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
   (or sudo update-initramfs -u -k <kerner version>)
2. sudo update-grub
```

I would like to fix or automate this once and for all, so that it won't happen again after the next update, but I am a complete newbie at tinkering with Linux.

Where should I start and how can a tackle this?

A quick solution would be appreciated, but I would also like to know what I need to study regarding ubuntu and linux in general, so that I won't have to bother you again with similar questions.

Thanks

edit:

```
cat /etc/initramfs-tools/update-initramfs.conf
```

produces the following:

```
update_initramfs=yes
backup_initramfs=no
```

edit 2:

```
df -h
```

regarding the boot partition produces

```
/dev/sdb2                    705M  172M  482M  27% /boot
/dev/sdb1                    511M  7,9M  504M   2% /boot/efi
```

Comment: `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/update-initramfs.conf` please add this to your question.

Comment: I’ve seen this sort of thing happen when the boot partition is low in space. Can you update the question to include the output of `df -h`?

Comment: did you get any errors, when you run update-initramfs by yourself?

Comment: The latest kernel version I have is 5.4.0-66-generic. 
I couldn't boot from that one, so I booted with the previous one (5.4.0-65), on which I had performed the "update-initramfs -u -k" command a few weeks ago. 
I just  did  "sudo update-initramfs -u -k all" and it produced:
"update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-65-generic". 
So, it updated only the current version that I used to log in, not the new one that has the issue. I have to explicitly ask it to update the 5.4.0-66 version (or the latest in any new update)

Comment: `sudo update-initramfs -c -v -k 5.4.0-66-generic`  please paste it here https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/

Comment: done: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/r9fcQpzT2c/  Also, ```sudo apt-get upgrade``` shows some errors: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/4jzxK3JdYn/

Comment: Oh, I see some package version from focal-proposed. Also a problem with  nvidia packages.  `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d` and `dkms status`  please.

Comment: The first one is here: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/TtTQf8XrwD/
and  `dkms statis ` says:

`nvidia, 415.27: added
nvidia, 460.39, 5.4.0-65-generic, x86_64: installed`